# R is not removing stop words

Tags: r, twitter, text-mining, tidy

I have searched tweets and have the following code. This code should remove stop words, numbers and URLS. It has removed about 1000 words but a few still remain. When I get the top 10 words, words like didn't and i'm appear. Is there something I am doing incorrectly? The stop words are present in tidytext. One more clarification item the after the antijoin on the stop words, 3 of the didn't does not remain and one still does. So the antijoin is handling some of the stop words.

```
    crTwts = costaRica %>% 
      mutate(
        # Remove http elements manually
         stripped_text = gsub("http\\S+","",text)
       ) %>% 
       select(stripped_text) %>%
      unnest_tokens(word, stripped_text) %>%
      anti_join(stop_words) %>%
      filter(is.na(as.numeric(word)))

#code to find top 10 words
crTwts %>%
  count(word, sort = TRUE) %>%
  top_n(10) %>%
  mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = word, y = n)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab(NULL) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "Count",
       y = "Unique words",
     title = "Unique word counts found in Costa Rica tweets")
```

Here is the data I get: 
[image]

Here is some sample data of the first 6 tweets in the costaRica list

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7onp.png) "WHAT DID THEY EAT? asks @SheilaGunnReid, who reports:\n\nTrudeau expensed $1200 for family meals on round trip flights to Costa Rica\n\nWATCH here: \n\n#cdnpoli #TrudeauWorstPM 2"
[2] "I swear you watch ONE Fortnite montage on Youtube and suddenly your entire reccommended section is: \nThe Box \U0001f4e6\nLet Her Go \U0001f48d\nCosta Rica \U0001f334\nBallin\U0001f3c0\nRoxanne \U0001f495\nBlueberry Faygo \U0001f347\nAddison Rae \U0001f483"
[3] "We had just qualified for the 2010 WC, my favorite memory from playing with @USMNT. Tonight will be my first time watching the last match of qualifying vs. Costa Rica at RFK. To the fans - thank you for inspiring me and motivating me through it all with this incredible gesture ❤️ "
[4] "@Thornburgurr @AMCx32 @nathanjmartin @RepGregStanton @netflix That proves she didn't kill him! She didn't have motive but other people around him did. He had mob ties in Costa Rica alonh with many \"girlfriends.\" The local sheriff who knows the case well said that Carole is not a suspect or even a person of interest."
[5] "@anassaifuddin You remember \U0001f60f\n\nCorrect! \U0001f919\n\nAndorra, Costa Rica, and Dominica are examples of countries that do not have an army."
[6] "Wooooow... should’ve been leaving to Costa Rica rn\U0001f612"

```
head(costaRica)
# A tibble: 6 x 90
  user_id status_id created_at          screen_name text  source
  <chr>   <chr>     <dttm>              <chr>       <chr> <chr> 
1 301896… 12475083… 2020-04-07 12:55:52 RebelNewsO… "WHA… Tweet…
2 159443… 12475862… 2020-04-07 18:05:09 GronKy_     "I s… Hoots…
3 493116… 12475692… 2020-04-07 16:57:47 CharlieDav… We h… Twitt…
4 118886… 12480996… 2020-04-09 04:05:30 Scaldriss   lmfa… Twitt…
5 776571… 12480996… 2020-04-09 04:05:18 annabeccax  twit… Twitt…
6 122272… 12480968… 2020-04-09 03:54:21 PatrickFar… "Cos… Twitt…
# … with 84 more variables: display_text_width <dbl>,
#   reply_to_status_id <chr>, reply_to_user_id <chr>,
#   reply_to_screen_name <chr>, is_quote <lgl>, is_retweet <lgl>,
#   favorite_count <int>, retweet_count <int>, quote_count <int>,
#   reply_count <int>, hashtags <list>, symbols <list>, urls_url <list>,
#   urls_t.co <list>, urls_expanded_url <list>, media_url <list>,
#   media_t.co <list>, media_expanded_url <list>, media_type <list>,
#   ext_media_url <list>, ext_media_t.co <list>,
#   ext_media_expanded_url <list>, ext_media_type <chr>,
#   mentions_user_id <list>, mentions_screen_name <list>, lang <chr>,
#   quoted_status_id <chr>, quoted_text <chr>, quoted_created_at <dttm>,
#   quoted_source <chr>, quoted_favorite_count <int>,
#   quoted_retweet_count <int>, quoted_user_id <chr>,
#   quoted_screen_name <chr>, quoted_name <chr>, quoted_followers_count <int>,
#   quoted_friends_count <int>, quoted_statuses_count <int>,
#   quoted_location <chr>, quoted_description <chr>, quoted_verified <lgl>,
#   retweet_status_id <chr>, retweet_text <chr>, retweet_created_at <dttm>,
#   retweet_source <chr>, retweet_favorite_count <int>,
#   retweet_retweet_count <int>, retweet_user_id <chr>,
#   retweet_screen_name <chr>, retweet_name <chr>,
#   retweet_followers_count <int>, retweet_friends_count <int>,
#   retweet_statuses_count <int>, retweet_location <chr>,
#   retweet_description <chr>, retweet_verified <lgl>, place_url <chr>,
#   place_name <chr>, place_full_name <chr>, place_type <chr>, country <chr>,
#   country_code <chr>, geo_coords <list>, coords_coords <list>,
#   bbox_coords <list>, status_url <chr>, name <chr>, location <chr>,
#   description <chr>, url <chr>, protected <lgl>, followers_count <int>,
#   friends_count <int>, listed_count <int>, statuses_count <int>,
#   favourites_count <int>, account_created_at <dttm>, verified <lgl>,
#   profile_url <chr>, profile_expanded_url <chr>, account_lang <lgl>,
#   profile_banner_url <chr>, profile_background_url <chr>,
#   profile_image_url <chr>
```

SOLUTION
There are different quotes (' versus ’). We have to sub out the curly quote for the straight quote and it finds the words in the stop words.

My new code

```
crTwts = costaRica %>% 
  mutate(
    # Remove http elements manually
    stripped_text = gsub("http\\S+","",text)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(stripped_text = gsub("’", "'", stripped_text, ignore.case = TRUE))  %>%
  select(stripped_text)  %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, stripped_text) %>%
  anti_join(all_cr_stop_words) %>%
  filter(is.na(as.numeric(word)))
```

Comment: The two examples you give are contractions. Does the `stop_words` list include contractions? With apostrophes? Maybe you also need to remove punctuation?

Comment: I checked and the stop words include contractions

Answer (score 1):

In the future please include sample data in your question. But for this one Try:

```
crTwts <- 
  costaRica %>% 
  mutate(
    # Remove http elements manually
    stripped_text = gsub("http.*|\\d+","",text)
  ) %>% 
  select(stripped_text) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, stripped_text) %>%
  filter(!(gsub("'", "", word) %in% gsub("'", "", stop_words$word)) & word != "")
```

Packages required above:

```
# Install pacakges if they are not already installed:
necessary_packages <- c("tidytext", "dplyr", "ggplot2")

# Create a vector containing the names of any packages needing installation:
new_packages <- necessary_packages[!(necessary_packages %in%
                                       installed.packages()[, "Package"])]

# If the vector has more than 0 values, install the new pacakges
# (and their) associated dependencies:
if (length(new_packages) > 0) {
  install.packages(new_packages, dependencies = TRUE)
}

# Initialise the packages in the session:
lapply(necessary_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)
```

Comment: I tried that and I received the same results. i'm and didn't are still in the top 10. The data I am pulling is tweets from Costa Rica. I tried to add in more information to the question

Comment: @RebeccaGonzalez please post sample data.

Comment: I hopefully addd in the data you were looking for.

Comment: @RebeccaGonzalez assuming you are manipulating a data.frame (or a similar list derivative such as a tibble) you can use: dput(costaRica) and copy the result from the console and paste it in your question.

Comment: That output was too large. Here is head(costaRica) in the question

Comment: @RebeccaGonzalez please use dput(head(costRica)) in order to produce a reproducible example.

Comment: @RebeccaGonzalez Im not sure if that did the trick but please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! This inspired me to figure something different out. The stop_words dictionary only has ' type of quote but the ones still appearing were ’. I had to sub those quotes for the correct ones and it solved the problem. I have the resolution in original question.

Comment: no worries please upvote and accept the answer if you found it useful.